# XDoclet - check annotation from other class

Tags: java, xdoclet

I'm using XDoclet to generate code:

```
/**
 * @diff.special
 */
public String myString;
```

Now I'd like to generate code depending on this annotation AND an annotation in an other class, i.e.

if annotation in class 1 = diff.special
===> decide what to do according to annotation in class 2
if annotation in class 1 = diff.normal
===> decide what to do according to annotation in class 3

How can I achieve that in my handler? When my ant task runs and is working on annotation in class 1, how can I get the annotations of class 2 or 3?

Thanks a LOT,

Haemi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it's the best way to do, but I solved it the following way:

```
  final XJavaDoc xJavaDoc = XDocletTagSupport.getXJavaDoc();
  final XClass xClass = xJavaDoc.getXClass(clazz.getCanonicalName());

  // iterate over all fields in the angebot class and...
  for (Object field : xClass.getFields(true)) {
    final XField xfield = (XField) field;
    // ... check if it contains the corresponding field, ...
    if (xfield.getName().contains(fieldNameToLookFor)) {
      return xfield;
    }
  }
```